# Adding values returned from a function to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

**Output:**

**cola**

**coke**

**3**

I want these values to be stored in an array. Please guide me how to!

**TIA**

This is the code:

```
int cola(string str)
{
    // word variable to store word
    string word;

    // making a string stream
    stringstream iss(str);

    // Read and print each word.
    while (iss >> word)
        {cout << word << endl;}}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    string s = "cola coke 3";
    cola(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a `std::vector<std::string>` and use `push_back` to add the strings to it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am new to this.

Comment: Like this: https://onlinegdb.com/GxuisXCPM

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```cpp
using std::string;

std::vector<string> cola(const string& str)
{
    // word variable to store word
    string word;

    // making a string stream
    stringstream iss(str);

    // vector containing words
    std::vector<string> temp;

    // Read and print each word.
    while (iss >> word)
        temp.push_back(word);

    return std::move(temp);
}
// Driver code
int main()
{
    string s = "cola coke 3";
    std::vector<string> array = cola(s);
    return 0;
}
```